# Django - didn't return an HTTPResponse Object

Tags: python, django

*Sorry if my english is bad, but if you need question, i'm here :)*

I saw many answers about this subject of HttpResponse object in Django, but i can't resolve it.

Normally the user insert his email address in order to recieve an email for his new password.

```
def forgottenPwdEmail(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordResetRequestForm(request.POST)
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
        user.confirmed = True
        user.save()
        sendResetPasswordMail(user, request.META['HTTP_HOST'])
    else:
        form = PasswordResetRequestForm()
        return render(request, 'front/reset_password_form.html', {'form': form})
```

After these error is displayed : "View" didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead. I can recieve the mail anyway, so the problem is in this function but i can't resolve it.

If you have some ideas, i am open :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a return in your if statement.

```
def forgottenPwdEmail(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordResetRequestForm(request.POST)
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
        user.confirmed = True
        user.save()
        return sendResetPasswordMail(user, request.META['HTTP_HOST'])
    else:
        form = PasswordResetRequestForm()
        return render(request, 'front/reset_password_form.html', {'form': form})
```

I am assuming that the sendResetPasswordMail is also returning a HttpResponse

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because your view doesn't return a response for a POST request.
You should add something like [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) page when the email is successfully sent, something like this:

```
def forgottenPwdEmail(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordResetRequestForm(request.POST)
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
        user.confirmed = True
        user.save()
        sendResetPasswordMail(user, request.META['HTTP_HOST'])

        return redirect('/password-reset-email-sent/')
     ......
```